# SQL Server : Insert statement Multiple values when 1 value stays the same untill all values inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do the following:

I have a table which has the columns:

```
id, manufacturerretailerid, categoryid, order
```

`order` can be null.

In the `manufacturerretailerid` and `categoryid` I need to do the following...

- if manufacturerretailer exists in the manufacturerretailer table insert categoryids:

  1
  2
  3
  4
  5

So I need to get the list of manufacturerRetailerIds:

```
select * 
from ManufacturerRetailers mr 
join manufacturers m on m.id = mr.ManufacturerId
where m.id = 14
```

For each of the ids that I get back I need to insert all the categoryids.

I've started with:

```
insert into ManufacturerRetailerCategories (ManufacturerRetailerId, CategoryId)
   select mr.id 
   from ManufacturerRetailers mr 
   join manufacturers m on m.id = mr.ManufacturerId
   where m.id = 14
```

but I'm not sure how to insert for each Manufacturerretailerid I get back 1,2,3,4,5 in the categoryid field.

So say we get the following:

Manufactureretailerids - 10,20,30,40,50

I want the following:

```
manufacturerretailerid     categoryid
10                         1
10                         2
10                         3
10                         4
10                         5
20                         1
20                         2
20                         3
20                         4
20                         5
```

and so on...

The actual categoryid list is about 30 long so I want to know if its possible to do this in one insert statement.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Edit:

I think this would add one value in:

```
insert into ManufacturerRetailerCategories (ManufacturerRetailerId, CategoryId)
values((select mr.id from ManufacturerRetailers mr 
join manufacturers m on m.id = mr.ManufacturerId
where m.id = 14) ,(1))
```

but I'd like to know how to add many

The category ids are actually a list of ids - at the moment there is not a relationship so I can t pull them from a table.

Comment: What database are you really using, SQL Server or MySQL?  Tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Why both MySQL and SQL Server tags? Don't tag products not involved!

Comment: You could write a stored procedure that runs through both your tables and just grabs the id's and inserts every pair into the column, but to be honest, this looks like a pretty strange thing to do because why would you need a relationship between every field in one table and every field in another table, that relationship won't really mean anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with a `cross join`.  Your question is not clear where the category values are actually located.  This may be what you want:

```
insert into ManufacturerRetailerCategories (ManufacturerRetailerId, CategoryId)
    select mr.id, c.categoryId
    from ManufacturerRetailers mr join
         manufacturers m
         on m.id = mr.ManufacturerId cross join
         (select distinct categoryId from manufacturerRetailers) c
    where m.id = 14 ;
```

If you have an explicit table of `Categories`, then you should use that instead of the subquery.

Comment: Hi Gordon the ManufacturerRetailer table does not have categories.  This is a separate table but does not currently have a relationship with manufactureretailers so I have a list of ids i.e. 1,2,3,4,5 which I need to add in with each Manufacturerretailer that exists.

Comment: @anna . . . Then use that table instead for the subquery.

Comment: thank you @Gordon I needed to create a temp table because of a foreign key constraint and then could use the above

Answer (score 1):

```
Here you go, hope it helps

insert into ManufacturerRetailerCategories (ManufacturerRetailerId, CategoryId)
    select mr.id, cat.id
    from ManufacturerRetailers mr join
         manufacturers m
         on m.id = mr.ManufacturerId cross join
         (SELECT * FROM ( VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4), (5) ) AS T1(id)) cat
    where m.id = 14 ;
```

Comment: thank you I think this would of worked if it was not for the foreign key constraint which I did not explain in the question.